# Copy vs ref benchmark: When are objects NOT passed in registers?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, c++20, benchmarking, pass-by-value

I heard that small objects are passed in CPU registers on function calls. I tried to search the maximum of when this is not anymore the case. I know that `string_view` is passed in registers. But what is the limit? I know this is architecture dependent, but it seems that even really large objects can be passed by registers. Compare the following:

(Check it out on [Quickbench](https://quick-bench.com/q/RY9In2xWtKKot_JDkgJWWTKjcdw))

```
struct big_object
{
    int a_;
    double b_;
    char c_;
    long long d_;
    bool e_;
    int f_;
    double g_;
    char h_;
    long long i_;
    bool j_;
    int k_;
    double l_;
    char m_;
    long long n_;
    bool o_;
};

big_object obj = {
    .a_ = 2, 
    .b_ = 2.5,
    .c_ = 'A',
    .d_ = 1203912045891732283,
    .e_ = false,
    .f_ = 10, 
    .g_ = 15.5,
    .h_ = 'D',
    .i_ = 123123123,
    .j_ = true,
    .k_ = 10, 
    .l_ = 15.5,
    .m_ = 'D',
    .n_ = 123123123,
    .o_ = true,
};

volatile int a;
volatile double b;
volatile char c;
volatile long long d;
volatile bool e;
volatile int f;
volatile double g;
volatile char h;
volatile long long i;
volatile bool j; 
volatile int k;
volatile double l;
volatile char m;
volatile long long n;
volatile bool o; 

int foo(big_object obj)
{
    a = obj.a_;
    b = obj.b_;
    c = obj.c_;
    d = obj.d_;
    e = obj.e_;
    f = obj.f_;
    g = obj.g_;
    h = obj.h_;
    i = obj.i_;
    j = obj.j_;
    k = obj.k_;
    l = obj.l_;
    m = obj.m_;
    n = obj.n_;
    o = obj.o_;
    return 1;
}

int foo_ref(big_object& obj)
{
    a = obj.a_;
    b = obj.b_;
    c = obj.c_;
    d = obj.d_;
    e = obj.e_;
    f = obj.f_;
    g = obj.g_;
    h = obj.h_;
    i = obj.i_;
    j = obj.j_;
    k = obj.k_;
    l = obj.l_;
    m = obj.m_;
    n = obj.n_;
    o = obj.o_;
    return 1;
}

static void Foo(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
    foo(obj);
  }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(Foo);

static void FooRef(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code before the loop is not measured
  for (auto _ : state) {
    foo_ref(obj);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(FooRef);
```

This compiles to exactly the same code and hence provide the same performance. I'm not an assembly pro, but I think I can see that a lot of registers are used to pass the object to the function. I know that there are even more physical CPU registers than logical ones, but does this mean that in any practical case, passing by reference is actually superfluous?

Comment: Your method copies the entire struct, so it's unsurprising that passing by reference doesn't save you anything versus passing a copy.

Comment: `foo` and `foo_ref` have been inlined in the assembly in the link. There is no function call happening at all.

Comment: First of all, it depends what ISA and calling-convention you're compiling for.  Quickbench compiles for x86-64 System V (used on all non-Windows x86-64 systems), so POD types up to 16 bytes wide can be passed in a pair of registers.  (Having a constructor or destructor can force it to have an address at all times, and get passed by reference.  Being larger than 16 bytes means it gets passed by *value* on the stack.)  As other commenters point out, your code isn't testing any of that, just looping on assignment to `volatile` globals after inlining, so a bunch of stores from regs.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury That is what I meant by "I'm not an assembly pro"... How can I improve the benchmark to not inline? I can't pass compilerflags...

Comment: Why would you do that? Are you going to write production code with inlining disabled? Of course not. Therefore, the reality is that you should always measure performance. Such questions are too broad, depend on architecture, compiler and many other things. And the answer won't be useful.

Comment: The best choice depends on the usage scenario, like whether the caller already has an existing object in memory it could pass a reference to, and how big it is, and how much of that object the callee actually needs to read.  (And thus whether you could pass those members individually.)  And whether the callee has to do anything else before using the incoming arg, e.g. call a different function, so it has to spill register args and reload later.  You could create benchmarks where by-reference is faster or slower for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

When function call is optimized out, when function is inlined, when you use pointers instead of objects and compiler decides that it's not worth copying, to name a few. There's no clear ruleset that compiler programmers have to follow other than C++ standard.

> but does this mean that in any practical case, passing by reference is actually superfluous?

No it isn't, references are a semantic construct and not an optimization "trick", so treat them as such.

References are simply aliases to variables. Everything else is quite literally up to the compiler. One useful properly of mutable reference is that mutated object actually changes on the caller side too once the function returns.

Sure, you can also use a pointer to achieve same thing, but an even more useful property of reference is a guarantee that the object you will be accessing is valid, while a pointer is nullable.

Speaking of which, even pointers are treated more or less the same nowadays, just look at `-findirect-inlining` in GCC, in similar way, `float*` can be optimized out by a compiler to simply a direct `float` copy. I can't remember the name of this optimization, but I know for a fact that GCC at least used to have it. And if you have a function like `float add(float* a, float* b)`, it will be inlined in most cases so it doesn't matter how you write it. It's simply a matter of choosing the most clear version.

Instead of worrying about things you don't understand, nor even need to, you should focus on semantics of your code. Let's be real, you're using a high level language like C++ instead of hand optimizing all ISA yourself is precisely because you want someone else to do hard work for you, so how come you don't trust them when that's the sole job they were given?

For example, it's pointless to take `const&` as parameter just to copy the object. If you want a copy of object in your function, then write so. Not only is this cleaner and more obvious to programmers that you will be copying, but it's clearer even to the compiler, which is also made by programmers. The fact that you benefit from certain optimizations is the only thing that's superfluous here. You're simply making it clear to anyone reading declaration that this object right there will be copied, that's all that matters. It doesn't matter how slow it is, you need to copy, so you copy.

Write code that's readable and understandable, you can worry about performance when you have a working program. If you can think of something "ingenious", the matter of fact is that compiler programmers thought of it before already.

And by the way, your benchmark doesn't benchmark anything. You're literally comparing identical code.

So like I already wrote before, do you want to copy the struct? Or simply reference something in it? That's the only thing that matters.